# Problems with solutions obtained from Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

I am solving a problem using `Reduce`, and having a difficulty with understanding the answers I obtained. I was solving `Reduce[abcd[q] = 0, q]` where

```
abcd[q_]=-0.003 + (800 a^3)/(3 q^3) - (400 a^2 Sqrt[(a^2 + k q)/q^2])/(
 3 q^2) - (100 k (k/q^2 - (2 (a^2 + k q))/q^3))/(
 3 Sqrt[(a^2 + k q)/q^2]) + (200 a^2 (k/q^2 - (2 (a^2 + k q))/q^3))/(
 3 q Sqrt[(a^2 + k q)/q^2])
```

It gave me back with 4 solutions - two real, two imaginary numbers. I put $a=1/4$, $k=1/10$ in the solutions, and obtained following numbers:

```
-26.8555 - 43.5291i
-26.8555 + 43.5291i
  4.8813
 48.2047
```

I put these numerical solutions back into `abcd[q]` with $a=1/4$, $k=1/10$, and obtained the following values:

```
-0.00593796 + 5.4479*10^-6 i
-0.00593796 - 5.4479*10^-6 i
 0.0656495
-1.30104*10^-18
```

Here is my first problem:

1. While the fourth solution looks sufficiently close to $0$, others do not really seem so. What's happening? Aren't they supposed to be solutions?

---

Perplexed, I tried to obtain using different approach: first, I put $a=1/4$, $k=1/10$ in `abcd[q]` and then tried `Reduce[abcd[q] = 0, q]`. This gave me back a *unique* solution that coincides with the fourth solution, $48.2047$.

To double check, I plotted `abcd[q]` with parameters $a=1/4$, $k=1/10$ and domain $[0, 100]$. It displayed a monotone decreasing function that intersects zero at $q=48.2047$. At $q=4.8813$, `abcd[q]` was in fact strictly positive, perhaps $0.0656495$ as calculated above. In sum, it strongly seems that $q=48.2047$ is the right answer.

Here comes my second question:

2. It seems that $q=48.2047$ is the right answer. Why did I get the other three answers from `Reduce`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions you obtained from Reduce are not valid for all combinations of values of your parameters $a$ and $k$.

Since you seem to be interested in real solutions, I will directly introduce that restriction to `Reduce`. It may then be informative to take a look at the results of `Reduce` that include conditions on the values of $a$ and $k$ for which the solutions returned are valid (the following was hand-formatted for legibility):

```
realsolutions = Reduce[abcd[q] == 0, q, Reals, Quartics -> False, Cubics -> False];
Shallow[realsolutions, 8]

(
 k < 0 && (
         (Root[<<1>>&,1]<a<Root[<<1>>&,1] && q==Root[<<1>>&,2])
         ||
         (Root[<<1>>&,1]<=a<=0&&q==Root[<<1>>&,1])
         ||
         (0<a<Root[<<1>>&,1]&&(q==Root[<<2>>]||q==Root[<<2>>]))
         ||
         (a==Root[<<1>>&,1]&&q==Root[<<1>>&,1])
        )
)
||
(
 k > 0 && (
         (a==Root[<<1>>&,2]&&q==Root[<<1>>&,1])
         ||
         (Root[<<1>>&,2]<a<0&&(q==Root[<<2>>]||q==Root[<<2>>]))
         ||
         (0<=a<Root[<<1>>&,2]&&q==Root[<<1>>&,2])
         ||
         (Root[<<1>>&,2]<=a<Root[<<1>>&,1]&&q==Root[<<1>>&,1])
        )
)
```

As you can see, there are no general expressions for the solutions that are independent of the values of the parameters $a,k$; `Reduce` returns a set of logical conditions for the solutions depending on the values of $k$ and $a$.

If you are interested in specific solutions for certain values of the parameters, you can use e.g. `Refine` together with any constraints on the parameter values to obtain the valid solution only.

For instance, in the case of $a=1/4$, $k=1/10$:

```
specificsolution = Refine[realsolutions, a == 1/4 && k == 1/10]
N@specificsolution

(* Out: 
   q == Root[398875000 - 81800000 #1 + 405 #1^3 + 648 #1^4 &, 2]
   q == 48.2047
*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It was very helpful. To restate your words: "all the four solutions are correct on some regions, but not on all regions" Is this right? Also, could you tell me about the notations such as <<1>>& and <<2>> ? I'm playing with the solution with myself, but I am not really getting what those symbols mean.

Comment: @ChangHwaLee Yes, that is what I mean. The `<<1>>` notation is called `Skeleton` notation; it is just shorthand for omitted parts of a complex expression. See [its documentation here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Skeleton.html).

Comment: Thank you, MarcoB! You saved my life, and paper! Thank you!

Comment: @ChangHwaLee I'm very glad it helped. If you think that my post answers your question, I'd appreciate it if you would consider accepting it formally by clicking the grey checkmark button next to it.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I wasn't aware of how this system works. Thank you for your answer and for telling me how to accept an answer. Wish this helps you! Thank you, again :)

Comment: @ChangHwaLee No problem! and thank you for the accept as well!